# How to shoot raycast, and display image on canvas

Tags: unity, c++, raycasting, ui-design

I have been trying to work on raycast, where if a raycast hits an object then an image will be displayed on the canvas, like on COD Warzone if I go to an elevator shaft, and look at the wire to go up, a thing will pop up and say "X". Im trying a similar thing, but have no idea how to even use raycasts let alone change the image.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: It's unclear to me from reading this question what you've tried and where specifically you've run into difficulty making it work. This kind of "interaction prompt" feature is easy to find documented in dozens of tutorials online — presumably you started by [doing a search and working through the available guides and documentation you found](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+raycast+interaction+prompt&ia=web)? What do you need explained here that has not already been covered in your research?